# Natbib: citations in small capitals

Tags: citing, natbib, overleaf

I want to make my citations in the text in small capitals. I work on overleaf and use natbib. I know people will tell me to use biblatex instead, but I use the draft from my university and I am afraid of everything crashing and changing when i try to switch to biblatex. Somewhere, I found the solution to use the following code. And the result looks exactly like I want.

```
\newcommand*{\citepold}{}
\let\citepold\citep
\renewcommand*{\citep}[1]{\textsc{\citepold{#1}}}
```

[image]

Except if I want to use "e.g." before the sources (USC02 is the bibtex key I gave to the source) like this:

```
\citep[e.g.][]{USC02}
```

[image]

Is there any way to fix this problem? I guess the issue starts already with my implementation to use small capitals, but since I am new to LaTeX I don't know how to handle the problem.

**Edit**

My bibliography style is `\bibliographystyle{apalike2}`

Other options I found in the draft:

```
\def\bibfont{\small}
\renewcommand{\bibsep}{5pt}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}
```

And I changed the color of the citations using:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks, colorlinks=true, citecolor=dark gray]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. The reason I ask it that it's safer and more robust to apply the `\textsc` directive as part of the bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico I added the info in the question, I hope this covers everything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`natbib` uses the internal command `\NAT@nmfmt` to typeset the name in the citation. Its default definition is `\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{{\NAT@up#1}}`, but we can shoehorn a `\scshape` in there for small caps.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{{\scshape\NAT@up#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \citep{elk}

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: "Lorem (Elk & Appleby, 1972)" "Elk & Appleby" in small caps]

---

I guess I'm contractually obliged to affirm that things are just as easy (if not easier) with `biblatex`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```